# razorpage constructor injection does not work, while view injection does work

Tags: razor-pages, constructor-injection

This is my code:

*.cshtml

```
@page
@model WebSite.Feature.Debugging.Areas.Debug.Pages.ListFeaturesModel
@{
}

<h1>Currently loaded features:</h1>
@foreach (var item in Model.Features)
{
    <li>@item.Name</li>
}
```

Codebehind:

```
public class ListFeaturesModel : PageModel
{
    public IEnumerable<IFeature> Features { get; }

    public ListFeaturesModel(IEnumerable<IFeature> features)
    {
        Features = features;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

The exception i get when navigating to the page:
[image: exception]

Oddly enough if i use @inject in the cshtml it works just fine. Has anyone run into this issue before?

The razorpage is placed inside a dynamically loaded Razor class library.

**Repo to reproduce**: https://github.com/taori/Sandbox.git

Build whole solution, run web application, navigate to MyFeature/Page1

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue was that i was loading plugins through Assembly.LoadFrom, instead of AssemblyLoadContext.Default.FromPath - While Load from works fine most of the time it struggles in netcore scenarios where dependencies are an issue.

Unfortunately the exception i got wasn't helpful so further digging was necessary.